# New subdomain not working on my VPS

Tags: subdomain

I've search for a solutions for days and I have no some up with anything.

I have a VPS with WHM and cpanel.
Currently I have 1 working sub-domain. However any new sub domains I add do not work.

With the working one I had an issue as it too was not working. I had contacted support and then it started to work. I'm not sure if they did anything to solve it I never got a reply. I would like to know for myself as cannot rely on support as they are slow and none responsive.

Over a week ago I have added 2 sub domains in the same fashion as the first.
So I know that it is possible to get sub domains to work but not sure how. I have checked my name servers but they are the same as the initial default. I have synced the DNS records through WHM. All the sub domains, both working and failing, are listing in WHM.

When accessing the sub domains that are failing I receive a 'Server not found' error.

What could be the issues? Why does one sub domain work and the rest don't?

Comment: Remove cpanel and WHM. Seriously. They're only complicating things and making it difficult, if not impossible for you to learn the skills needed to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Currently this is not an option.

Comment: When you say the sub-domains return "server not found", is this because they are not resolving to an IP address? Can you ping the sub-domain? I'm guessing this is a DNS related issue from the above.

Comment: I have no idea why I am receiving "server not found" errors. This is when I input the subdomain into a browser. I can ping the working subdomain. But the other 2 fail when attempting to ping.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the following was working: `www.example.com/subdomain`

But `subdomain.example.com` was not.

I realized that my default index was: `/subdomain/index.htm`. I renamed it to `/subdomain/index.html`.

Now, `subdomain.example.com` is working.

Note: it should be place to force to look for index.htm too, but I think I can't access to those config files with my free account.